# Replace string in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to replace a string into Razor view and for some reason it does not work

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PasswordExpired.Replace("True", "Yes"))</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Property `PasswordExpired` is a `bool`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the typeof `PasswordExpired` and what is its value?

Comment: It is a boolean and have True/False value.

Answer (score 0):

It works nice with this code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td nowrap="">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)</td>
        
        @{
            if (item.PasswordExpired != null)
            {
                string isPasswordExpired = item.PasswordExpired.Replace("True", "Yes").Replace("False", "No");
                <td>@isPasswordExpired</td>
            }
            else
            {
                string isPasswordExpired = "";
                <td>@isPasswordExpired</td>
            }
        }
    </tr>
}
```